# Combinations of distinct and identical subsets

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Let 50 guests come to a wedding gala. How many ways are there for all guests to sit in 5 distinct tables of 10 people capacity each? The order in which the guests are seated does not matter.

I understand that this is a combinatorics problem as the guests' sitting order does not matter. On the other hand the tables are distinct (and thus their ordering does matter?) so I get that I need to use permutations too.

What I have thought so far is that for a given table there are:

$$\binom{50}{10}$$

But then again I have to consider the fact that tables are distinct too. What is the proper way to work around that problem after all?

Answer (score 1):

${50 \choose 10}{40 \choose 10}{30 \choose 10}{20 \choose 10}$ - Choose the 10 occupants of the "red" table. Then the 10 of the "yellow", and so on.

If sitting order matters and the tables are round, you should multiply by $(9!)^5$.

If the tables are the same (it only matters who sits with whom, not at which table) you should divide by $5!$ (permitting the groups between the tables).

Comment: Why is that ${50 \choose 10}{40 \choose 10}{30 \choose 10}{20 \choose 10}$ indicates the distinction of the tables?

Comment: Because if group A was chosen in the first step and B in the second step, we get a different sitting than if B was chosen in the first step and A in the second step (the first chosen group gets a particular pre-assigned table - the red one). Think of two dice. You have $6\cdot 6$ options because you assign one value for the first die and one for the second, and they are different. If you can't tell the dice apart, you'll have fewer results to count.

Comment: Great! I get it. Thank you very much. Could you also explain why do I have to divide by $5!$ if the table ordering does not matter?

Comment: Because only the groups matter. If the groups are A,B,C,D,E, we counted every permutation of these groups as a different sitting. ABCDE and BACDE are different since someone else is sitting in the red table. So you want to calculate all the 5! permutations of ABCDE as one.

Comment: If sitting order matters why shouldn't I mutliply by $(10!)^5$?

Comment: I assumed it's a round table, so ordering people in a circle is 9!. For different tables, you'll get different answers. If all sit in a row ("last supper") then 10! is true.